# Pass Comma Separated String to SSRS

Tags: database, oracle, reporting-services, report

I have a comma separated string being passed in front-end of SSRS. How do my query recognize it in backend and not treat whole string as single ?

For eg: I type "*Harry, Potter, Book*" in input field of SSRS, I want each string to split up and pass to back-end query as.

```
Select * from tbl_test where name in ('harry', 'potter','book')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the front end pass the input in PLSQL Block like below

```
PROCEDURE p1(inparam varchar2)
IS 
  v_inparam varchar2(100);

BEGIN

v_inparam := inparam;

Select * into <object> from tbl_test where name in
  (select trim(regexp_substr(v_inparam ,'[^,]+', 1, level)) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(v_inparam , '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
END;
```